# How to use spotlight for system commands such as shutdown?

Tags: macos, spotlight, shutdown

I want to type in **Spotlight** commands such as `shutdown`, `reboot`, `suspend` or `lock` and make it execute it, just like Alfred does.

How to make this possible with Spotlight?

Comment: So the answer is not possible with spotlight itself? I don' t want to install alfred.

Comment: You could save scripts for the commands as applications in AppleScript Editor. For example use `tell application "System Events" to shut down` to shut down, `tell application "loginwindow" to «event aevtrlgo»` to log out, or `do shell script "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend"` to lock the screen.

Comment: Are you opposed to using the built in keyboard shortcuts?